# Salvar arquivo compactado em outro diretório

Tags: php

Tenho essa função que faz o `.zip` da pasta atual para salvar. Porém quero que salve na pasta `backup`.

```
$data = date("d_m_y");
$exten = "_backup.zip"; // Nome final com extensão

class Zipper extends ZipArchive 
{
    public function Compact($cwd) {
        $open = opendir($cwd);
        while($folder = readdir($open))
        {
            if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..')
            {
                if (is_dir($cwd.'/'.$folder))
                {
                    $dir = str_replace('./', '',($cwd.'/'.$folder));    
                    $this->addEmptyDir($dir);                   
                    $this->Compact($dir);
                } 
                elseif (is_file($cwd.'/'.$folder))
                {
                    $arq = str_replace('./', '',$cwd.'/'.$folder);                      
                    $this->addFile($arq);                                               
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
}

$zip = new Zipper();
if ($zip->open($data.$exten, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true){
    $zip->Compact(".");
}
$zip->close();`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O diretório onde queira salvar deve ser passado como parâmetro ao abrir o arquivo:

Exemplo: `./backup/arquivo.zip`

```
$diretorio = "./backup/";
$zip->open($diretorio.$data.$exten, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)
```

Lembrando que podemos utilizar a função [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getcwd.php) para pegar o diretório atual:

```
$diretorio = getcwd() . "/backup/";
$zip->open($diretorio.$data.$exten, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas foi necessário deixar o caminho do diretório sem a primeira barra: $diretorio = "backup/"

Comment: Eu corrigi a resposta, coloquei a função `getcwd();`  que pega o diretorio que você está atualmente e coloca a pasta `backup`. Sempre que uma resposta estiver correta, marque-a como correta para que outros com a mesma dúvida saiba que a solução proposta funcionou. Outra coisa, para conseguir dar certo utilize `./backup/arquivo.zip` utilize o `.` no inicio.